# Cannot resolve Nginx 502 Bad Gateway and error of connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx-config, adonis.js

I am an amateur programmer and currently lost in deploying my app to a digital ocean cloud server. I followed numerous online tutorials and manage to setup SSH, NodeJS, PM and Nginx. Everything works fine with the Nginx welcome page displayed. However, I got stuck when I tried to configure the Nginx config file to proxy into my Adonis app. I tried the setup with Adonis documentation but it wont works as well.

The browser display 502 Bad Gateway with the error log displaying connect () failed (111: Connection refused). I tried to read more examples on the net but unable to find one.

How to do the setup the Nginx to run my adonis apps?

Nginx config

[image]

PM2 status

[image]

Port network

[image]

Connection Error

[image]

502 Bad Gateways

[image]